# Rails Includes/Order/Limit Returning Wrong Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

When I order a record set by reverse ID (i.e. .order("id desc")) and set .limit(10), I get the last ten records from the table.

If I throw in an includes(:whatever) in there, I get the FIRST ten records, sorted in reverse (10, 9, 8, 7, etc.).

So, example that returns the right results (245978, 245977, 245976, etc):

```
assets = Asset.order("assets.id desc").limit(records_per_query).where("asset_type_id not in (?)", skip_asset_types)
```

Example that returns the wrong results (10, 9, 8, etc):

```
assets = Asset.includes(:asset_type).order("assets.id desc").limit(records_per_query).where("asset_type_id not in (?)", skip_asset_types)
```

Any idea how to make the second query return the right set of results?  I'd rather avoid making the n+1 queries (it actually includes more than the one relation, simplifying for the sake of a readable example).

Comment: it seems there should be includes(:asset_type) instead of include(:asset_type)

Comment: Yes... I modified the code from what's actually in my application.  You can assume that anything that would actually cause it to not return anything at all (as opposed to the wrong 10 records) is a typo in putting it here, as otherwise I wouldn't know that it was returning the wrong set.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior, so I suggest checking what actually you receive in your second query. Please make sure that it contained 245978, 245977, 245976 as well

Comment: That's my point... it does NOT contain those assets, but it should.  Doing nothing but adding includes causes it to get the first ten assets and then order them by the order statement, rather than ordering THEN getting the first ten.  In other words, the first statement orders, then limits, while the second limits, then orders.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in there. `"asset_type_idnot in (?)"`. Just sayin' :)

Comment: There, I fixed my typo... I was altering the actual code from my application, because it would have needlessly complicated the issue, and I missed that.